# EF Core migration issue with a jsonb column

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

I have a project that has a `Contact` entity like this

```cs
public class Contact
{
    public List<PhoneContact> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneContact
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

internal class ContactConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
    {
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Phones)
                   .HasColumnType("jsonb");
        }
    }
}
```

The generated migration is doing this

```cs
namespace MyApp.Migrations.ApplicationMigrations
{
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Contacts",
                schema: "app",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Phones = table.Column<List<PhoneContact>>(type: "jsonb", nullable: false)
                }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApp.Migrations.ApplicationMigrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationMigrationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationMigrationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                    b.Property<List<PhoneContact>>("Phones")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("jsonb");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to drop the `Phones` column from my `Contact` entity and I want to delete the `PhoneContact` class that is not used anymore.

The problem is that old migrations are using this class and the project does not want to compile anymore because I deleted it.

What would be the best way to handle this case without destroying all migrations?